# How to use sed to print part of a string containing hashes (or any alternative solution)?

Tags: sed, awk, grep, string

I am trying to print out a specific string within a line with sed.

The first problem is that I have some difficulties finding a string which contains slashes, I already tried some solutions provided in other threads but was unsuccessful, hopefully someone can help me.

I have a file called output.log.

An example of a line is:

```
013-11-08 19:45:52 evtlog.bad PROD/INSE/6004113 2012-11-08 19:04:06 /test11/golf/TierTwo/2013-11/evtlog.log
```

So with sed I want to print out only below string from this line:

/test11/golf/TierTwo/2013-11/evtlog.log

And I want to find the string in this line with:  "golf/TierTwo/2013-11"

So I would use for example:

```
sed 'golf/TierTwo/2013-11' output.log
```

And get an output of:

```
/test11/golf/TierTwo/2013-11/evtlog.log
```

How can I achieve this?

If there would be a better solution instead of sed, it would be welcome also.
My goal is to use this in a script, either bash or perl

Comment: Could specify if it has to be solved with `sed` or if you just want to solve the problem? Because every problem that can be solved with `sed` can and will also be solved with `awk` or `perl`. If you don't care it is better to rewrite your question so it is more general.

Comment: Hi, the problem can be solved with any solution, will edit my question.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `grep` supports the `-o` or `--only-matching` flag, you could grep for the string, surrounded by any contiguous non-whitespace characters

```
grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*golf/TierTwo/2013-11[^[:blank:]]*' output.log
/test11/golf/TierTwo/2013-11/evtlog.log
```

or (if it supports the perl-style `\S` class)

```
grep -Eo '\S*golf/TierTwo/2013-11\S*' output.log
/test11/golf/TierTwo/2013-11/evtlog.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` instead of sed:

```
awk 'index($0,"golf/TierTwo/2013-11")>0 { print $7 }' output.log
```

this will search the string in each line, if an index is found 7th word will be printed.

Comment: Hi, it seems this command prints out the 7th word of every line in the document.

Comment: but not specific the line that contains the string.

Comment: @Flemx, yes because `"golf/TierTwo/2013-11"` being a string and non-empty, it means true. Here, you want to use the regexp matching operator, so `/.../` (though you'd need to escape the `/` within) or `$0 ~ "..."`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -naE 'say $F[6] if m!golf/TierTwo/2013-11!' logfile
```

`perl -nae` makes perl behave in a awk way...